# Average a large array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, postgresql, average

I've got what ultimately amounts to a large array of numbers (pulled from a database).

So, it might look like: `[1,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,1]`

Except it could be 50,000 numbers instead a few dozen. The lowest number will always be `1` and highest is `3`.

What I need to do is find some sort of rolling average so I can display the data in a manageable line chart.

So maybe average the numbers of every 5-10 data points? Just not sure what the best way to process something like this.

NOTE: Not looking to get a single average. I'm looking to distill the whole array down into a few more average points. So, a data set of 1000 points might be broken down into 10 average numbers.

Comment: As a sidenote, the highest in your example (before editing was) not 3. ) But the real question is, how precise your 'average' should be?

Comment: is there a reason you're not just selecting the average directly from the database?

Comment: @mcfinnigan I don't need a single average...I need multiple averaged data points. So a data set of 1,000 numbers might have 10 average points.

Comment: @Shpigford your database can produce averages over slices by grouping by row number.  The DB is almost certainly going to be at least an order of magnitude faster than ruby at this.

Comment: @dbenhur: Care to add an answer with that solution, then?

Comment: producing row number varies among dbs, what flavor do you run?

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL

Comment: PostgreSQL answer [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15528217/1074296).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > a = [1,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,1]
 => [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
1.9.3p327 :002 > a.each_cons(10).map { |subarray| subarray.reduce(0.0, :+) / subarray.size }
 => [1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.9, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 1.9]
```

This is not good in terms of performance though. It's O(NM), where N is the size of the array, and M is the size of the window (10 in this case).

UPD: Or you can use `each_slice`, if you need to "reduce" the array size significantly:

```
1.9.3p327 :002 > a.each_slice(10).map { |subarray| subarray.reduce(0.0, :+) / subarray.size }
 => [1.8, 2.0, 2.1, 1.0]
```

Comment: For what the OP wants, "So maybe average the numbers of every 5-10 data points?", `each_cons` should be replaced with `each_slice`.

Comment: What's the difference between what `each_cons` and `each_slice` is doing? `each_slice` is probably what I'm after...but curious what exactly `each_cons` is doing.

Comment: `each_slice` takes each `n` elements, whereas `each_cons` slides a window of size `n` forward, one element at a time. [Enumerable Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html)

Answer (score 4):

This sliced average can be acquired directly via the database select. Your database engine is almost certain to do grouping and average calculation at least an order of magnitude faster than ruby, in addition, you will transfer far less data over the wire from your db to your program and dramatically reduce the number of objects instantiated in your ruby program to represent the result set.

So, if your original query looked something like this (in Postgresql):

```sql
select value from mytable;
```

You can modify it to produce average over every ten items like this:

```sql
select avg(value) as chunk_avg, row/10 as chunk
from 
  (select value, row_number() over () - 1 as row
   from mytable) x
group by chunk
order by chunk;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/314c3/6)

If you don't want the chunk number in the result, you could wrap this in another outer select that just projects `chunk_avg`, or drop the `chunk` field form the `select` clause and literally replace `chunk` with `row/10` in the `group by` and `order by` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The average of averages is **NOT** the same as the overall average. Unless you don't demand much precision, or don't require sub-sets of averages, I don't recommend it.

Comment: It's not really an "average of averages"...it's just breaking down a bunch of numbers into a few averages over the span of the data instead of a single average.

Comment: Then your idea is golden (averaging in sub-sets)